# When does the sum of irrationals equals a rational?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Is there a rule for when the sum of two irrationals equals a rational?

That is, if $A,B \in \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$ and $A+B \in \mathbb{Q}$

can we say something particular about $A,B$?

What leads me to this question is:

I want to show that $6\sqrt{2} + k\sqrt{(13+6\sqrt{2})} \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow k$ is irrational

*I thought of trying to show the difference between them must be a product of the irrational and some rational scalar, but no success.

Comment: Please use mathjax. The device I'm viewing this on doesn't have all of the characters you have used, and it's possible I could answer your question if I knew what they were.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $k$ is rational. Then $k\sqrt{13 + 6\sqrt 2} = q - 6\sqrt 2$, where $q\in\mathbb Q$. Now, squaring both sides gives
$$
6(k^2 + 2q)\sqrt 2 = q^2 + 72 - 13k^2.
$$
But this is impossible since everything here, except $\sqrt 2$, is rational.

EDIT: No, I was wrong. Could be that $k^2+2q = 0$, i.e., $q = -k^2/2$. Setting this into the original equation, one obtains
$$
k = -\sqrt{13 + 6\sqrt 2} \pm \sqrt{13 - 6\sqrt 2}.
$$
Now, it remains for you to show that both these numbers are irrational.

Comment: can you explain what is wrong with the original reasoning? Is something lost when squaring? I've tried the same approach originally and found some examples that contradict it..

Comment: I would be really interested in your contradicting examples since I think the claim is true. As I said, we have a problem in our reasoning when $k^2+2q = 0$ because in this case, the LHS (in my answer) is zero and no contradiction occurs. So, we have to show that also this case is impossible if $k$ is rational.

Comment: How about for $x=6\sqrt{2}+k\sqrt{11+6\sqrt{2}}$? This one gave me trouble.

Comment: Why do you now come up with a new one? Have you proved the original one?

Comment: Ok, I'll add context: the aim is to show that the expansion of $\sqrt{11+6\sqrt{2}}$ over the rationals is 2  and not 4 as is the expansion of $\sqrt{13+6\sqrt{2}}$. That is, by following your ORIGINAL method I was able to show, unless I made a mistake, that $\sqrt{11+6\sqrt{2}}$ has a degree 2 polynomial for which it is its root. Where $\sqrt{13+6\sqrt{2}}$ doesn't (over Q)

Comment: What is an "expansion of an irrational number over the rationals"??? I can't follow you. Is this related to the original question?

Comment: Did my edit clarify my confusion, Friedrich?

Comment: Sorry, but you write in a very confusing way. **Every number** is the root of a polynomial. I guess you mean one with rational coefficients, right? Then we are talking about algebraic numbers.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote, polynomials over Q.

Comment: So, how is this new question related to the original one (which was "I want to show that $6\sqrt 2 + k\sqrt{13+6\sqrt 2}\in\mathbb Q$ $\Rightarrow$ $k$ is irrational.")? And (as I already asked) were you able to solve the original one?

Comment: Ok, put simply. Can you show that $6\sqrt 2 + k\sqrt{11+6\sqrt 2}\in\mathbb Q$ implies k is irrational? To answer your question, I tried your original method; but as this second example shows it doesn't always work. I did not yet solve your edit solution, if that is what you're asking

Comment: Alright... What goes wrong when you try to do the same with $11$ instead of $13$?

Comment: Ok, in this case, it is wrong that $k$ is necessarily irrational. A counterexample is $k = -6$ and $q = -18$. The reason is that here $k^2 + 2q = 0$ is possible - in contrast to the first case.

Comment: Yes, I see; I misread something in your answer when posted 'is something lost when squaring'. Thank you. If you have an idea to the general question I would love to read it. Thanks again..

Comment: Since you weren't able to explain the general question to me in understandable terms, I don't know what it is.

Comment: Note that $q>0.$ So, $k^2+2q>0.$

Comment: No, q is not necessarily positive.

Answer (score 4):

Let us call $$x=6\sqrt{2}+k\sqrt{13+6\sqrt{2}}.$$ Then

$$x-6\sqrt{2}=k\sqrt{13+6\sqrt{2}}.$$ Squaring

$$x^2-12\sqrt{2}x+72=13k^2+6\sqrt{2}k^2.$$ Rearranging terms

$$x^2+72-13k^2=6\sqrt{2}k^2+12\sqrt{2}x=\sqrt{2}(6k^2+12x).$$

Since we are assuming that $x$ is rational, the left hand side is rational if $k$ is rational. But for $k$ rational the right hand side is irrational. This gives a contradiction. So, $k$ must be irrational.

Comment: Uh, there is something missing. I will edit my answer...